# looking for a way to upload a video to youtube with jquery without postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to create asp.net page that will upload a video to youtube without refresehing/postback. I am using a asp:FileUpload control to let users select a file to upload. In jquery, I am trying to read the full path and filename of the file selected, but it gives me "c:/fakepath/correctfilename.txt". I did some researches and saw the security facts. When posting a video to youtube, youtube wants the full path. how am I supposed to fix this?

here is my code so far to get the full path

```
$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').change(function(event) {
   alert($('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').val());
});
```

this shows the dialog box with "c:/fakepath/corectfilename.txt". how can I get real path? I read that it is imposibble to upload to youtube with javascript, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

there is no way for javascript to access to file's full path on user's computer for security reasons. javascript give a path like "c:/fakepath/correctname.mp4". therefore, you cannot upload a video to youtube because youtube wants full path to the video file from your computer.

but u can upload videos to other servers because full path is not needed.